# Manipulating datetime columns with time units using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In SQL, `DATEDIFF(HOUR, column1, column2)` is used to find difference *in hours* between 2 datetime columns.

Also, `select DATEADD(HOUR, 5, column)` is used to Add 5 *hours* to a `datetime` column.

**Is there any way to do these using Hibernate?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Formula annotation in your Entity class in hibernate to calculate the expression. Like this

```
    @Formula("DATEDIFF(HOUR, column1, column2)")
    private int theDiff;

    @Formula("DATEADD(HOUR, 5, column)")
    private int add;
```

See more [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) and [here](http://gokhan.ozar.net/hibernate-derived-properties-formula-annotation/)

Comment: Oh.. Great, thanks. But, if i want to find the diff between 2 different columns during retrieve.. then how can i do..??